Google Sheets - Publish to Web not working
Having used publish to web on Google Sheets for a few years now, it seems to have had an update over the last few months and now it doesn't work as it used to.
I have a spreadsheet which has multiple worksheets and there are specific ones I want to publish to web to show on a forum. Previously this worked without issue but now it basically just shows all worksheets, irrelevant of which ones I select to be published.
Below is a screenshot of the publish to web screen I have and as you can see I have selected worksheets 'Week 1', 'Week 2' & 'Week 3' to be published but at the moment it is also showing week 4 when I post the link on the forum and week 4 should remain hidden.
Am I suddenly doing something wrong?


This is a recent change in how File > Share > Publish to web works. The issue has been escalated to Google. To get notified of a possible fix, click I have the same question and Subscribe at publishing only selected tabs from Sheets to the web displaying ALL content.

Ahhh, I have done as suggested. I shall continue to just continue to hide the sheets I don't wish to share until a fix is found
